# method that returns the user's name and surname and method that returns a boolean value according to whether the user is an adult or not

Tags: php, class

```
<?php
  class User {
    var $id;
    var $first_name;
     var $last_name;
     var $age;
     function construct($id,$first_name,$last_name,$age){
        $this>=$id;
        $this>=$first_name;
        $this>=$last_name;
        $this>=$age;
      }
      public function getFirstName(){
            return $this->last_name;
    }
public function getLastName(){
            return $this->last_name;
}
     function values(){
       echo "User id: {$this->id} <br/> First name : {$this->fname} <br/> Last name : {$this ->lname}";
     }
     function setAge($age){
       if(is_numeric($age) && $age >= 18){ $this->$age = $age;
       }
      else { throw new Exception("Age is not valid"); }
    }
}

$user = new User (001,'Vladmir','Bozic');
$lastName = $user->getLastName();
$firstName = $user->getFirstName();
?>
```

/*I managed to change the lines of code but it is not writing it on my page. There is nothing when i open up in browser. In my task i need to class constructor,
a method that returns the user's name and surname,
a method that returns a boolean value according to whether the user is an adult or not.

Comment: do you have the method getLastName() defined ?

Comment: you don't need to `var` your variable declarations; you should be setting the permissions; `public` or `private` or `protected`

Comment: please include some text to your question to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `$this>=$id` looks pretty strange to me - shouldn't that read `$this->id = $id`?

Comment: yep, the construct is wrong all of them are wrong instead of **$this>=$id** they should be **$this->id;** author take an eye on this .

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method that does not exists.

You can read the value from the variable directly for example:

```
$user = new User (001,'Vladmir','Bozic');
$lastName = $user->last_name;
$firstName = $user->first_name;
```

Or you have to create the methods to be able to call them.

```
public function getLastName(){
     return $this->last_name;
}

public function getFirstName(){
     return $this->first_name;
}
```

Comment: I managed to figure out meanwhile. I just need to write the results on page but is empty. Can you help me abouth that ?

Comment: Which method are you talking about?

Comment: After creating a class, you also need to create an object that represents an instance of the created class. Above the object you need to call both methods and display the execution result on the pages. That is the task

Comment: @NicoHaase Author updated the question and added my method..